# Powershell Dynamics CRM, how to add two queues to a user

Tags: powershell, dynamics-crm

I have created a user and I am trying to assign him two queues n°1 et n°2. The problem is that the code I used only replaces the last queue.

```
Import-Module C:\Powershell\CRMBuzz\CRMBuzzPowerTools_Module_2_0_0_15_Setup\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\CRMBuzzPowerTools\CRMBuzz.PowerTools.PSSnapin.dll -Force -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -DisableNameCheckin
$connString="Url=https://crmlab:5555/CRMLab;Username=test@crm.lab;password=******;"
$CRMConn = New-OrganizationConnection -ConnectionString $connString -Verbose
$queue_ref0=Get-EntityReferenceByName -OrganizationService $CRMConn -EntityName "queue" -FindFieldName "name" -ReferenceValue "TEST1"
$queue_ref1=Get-EntityReferenceByName -OrganizationService $CRMConn -EntityName "queue" -FindFieldName "name" -ReferenceValue "TEST2"
$userent=Search-EntityFull -OrganizationService $CRMConn  -EntityObject systemuser -FieldName domainname -SearchValue "TEST\P_TEST"
[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference] $userent.Attributes["queueid"]=$queue_ref0
[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference] $userent.Attributes["queueid"]=$queue_ref1
Update-Record -OrganizationService $CRMConn -EntityObject $userent –verbose
```

I tried another method I found online but it's returning incompatibility errors.

```
Move-CrmRecordToQueue -EntityLogicalName account -Id 5ff140ea-95ed-e811-80e9-005056bd633b -QueueName "TEST1" -WorkingUserId 5bf140ea-95ed-e811-80e9-005056bd633b
```

I have also tried this but don't know the parameters to use.

```
Import-Module C:\Powershell\Handy.Crm.Extensions.Powershell.Cmdlets
$cred = Get-Credential
$CRMConn = Connect-CrmOnPremDiscovery -Credential $cred -ServerUrl https://crmlab:5555/CRMLab
Set-CRMQueueForUser -Connection $CRMConn -UserId 5bf140ea-95ed-e811-80e9-005056bd633b -QueueId 023963ca-08a5-e611-80c6-00155d011760
```

**EDIT**

James' answer cleared a few things for me. Above I was trying to add two queues to the default queue of user, which is impossible. I think I should add them in the field that's below the default queue like in this picture (don't know this field's name):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with [PowerShell](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.Xrm.Data.Powershell/2.1/Content/Microsoft.Xrm.Data.PowerShell.psm1).

For example, [queuemembership_association](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/entities/queue#BKMK_queuemembership_association) link can be created using the below cmdlet. (Pls test it as I have not tested this yet)

```
PS C:\>$systemuser = Get-CrmRecord systemuser 00005a70-6317-e511-80da-c4346bc43d94 name

 PS C:\>$queue = Get-CrmRecord queue 66005a70-6317-e511-80da-c4346bc43d94 fullname

 PS C:\>Add-CrmRecordAssociation $systemuser $queue queuemembership_association
```

Two functions are available for associating single entity record and associating on bulk namely, `Add-CrmRecordAssociation` and  `Add-CrmMultiRecordAssociation`. Pasting the related cmdlets along with examples:

```
#CreateEntityAssociation
function Add-CrmRecordAssociation{

<#
 .SYNOPSIS
 Associates two records for N:N relationship.

 .DESCRIPTION
 The Add-CrmRecordAssociation cmdlet lets you associate two records for N:N relationship by specifying relatioship logical name. 

 There are two ways to specify records.
 
 1. Pass EntityLogicalName and record's Id for both records.
 2. Get a record object by using Get-CrmRecord/Get-CrmRecords cmdlets, and pass it for both records.

 You can specify relationship logical name for the association.

 .PARAMETER conn
 A connection to your CRM organizatoin. Use $conn = Get-CrmConnection <Parameters> to generate it.

 .PARAMETER CrmRecord1
 A first record object which is obtained via Get-CrmRecord/Get-CrmRecords. When you pass CrmRecord, then you don't use EntityLogicalName/Id.

 .PARAMETER CrmRecord2
 A second record object which is obtained via Get-CrmRecord/Get-CrmRecords. When you pass CrmRecord, then you don't use EntityLogicalName/Id.

 .PARAMETER EntityLogicalName1
 A logicalname for first Entity. i.e.)accout, contact, lead, etc..

 .PARAMETER Id1
 An Id (guid) of first record

 .PARAMETER EntityLogicalName2
 A logicalname for second Entity. i.e.)accout, contact, lead, etc..

 .PARAMETER Id2
 An Id (guid) of second record

 .PARAMETER RelationshipName
 A N:N relationship logical name.

 .EXAMPLE
 Add-CrmRecordAssociation -conn $conn -EntityLogicalName1 account -Id1 00005a70-6317-e511-80da-c4346bc43d94 -EntityLogicalName2 contact -Id2 66005a70-6317-e511-80da-c4346bc43d94 -RelationshipName new_accounts_contacts

 This example associates an account and a contact records through new_accounts_contacts custom N:N relationship.

 .EXAMPLE
 Add-CrmRecordAssociation account 00005a70-6317-e511-80da-c4346bc43d94 contact 66005a70-6317-e511-80da-c4346bc43d94 new_accounts_contacts
 
 This example associates an account and a contact records through new_accounts_contacts custom N:N relationship by ommiting parameters names.
 When ommiting parameter names, you do not provide $conn, cmdlets automatically finds it.

 .EXAMPLE
 PS C:\>$account = Get-CrmRecord account 00005a70-6317-e511-80da-c4346bc43d94 name

 PS C:\>$contact = Get-CrmRecord contact 66005a70-6317-e511-80da-c4346bc43d94 fullname

 PS C:\>Add-CrmRecordAssociation -conn $conn -CrmRecord1 $account -CrmRecord2 $contact -RelationshipName new_accounts_contacts

 This example retrieves and stores an account and a contact records to variables, then pass them to Add-CrmRecordAssociation cmdlets.

 .EXAMPLE
 PS C:\>$account = Get-CrmRecord account 00005a70-6317-e511-80da-c4346bc43d94 name

 PS C:\>$contact = Get-CrmRecord contact 66005a70-6317-e511-80da-c4346bc43d94 fullname

 PS C:\>Add-CrmRecordAssociation $account $contact new_accounts_contacts

 This example retrieves and stores an account and a contact records to variables, then pass them to Add-CrmRecordAssociation cmdlets.

#>

    [CmdletBinding()]
    PARAM(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient]$conn,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1, ParameterSetName="CrmRecord")]
        [PSObject]$CrmRecord1,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2, ParameterSetName="CrmRecord")]
        [PSObject]$CrmRecord2,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1, ParameterSetName="NameWithId")]
        [string]$EntityLogicalName1,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2, ParameterSetName="NameWithId")]
        [guid]$Id1,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=3, ParameterSetName="NameWithId")]
        [string]$EntityLogicalName2,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=4, ParameterSetName="NameWithId")]
        [guid]$Id2,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=5)]
        [string]$RelationshipName
    )

    $conn = VerifyCrmConnectionParam $conn; 

    if($CrmRecord1 -ne $null)
    {
        $EntityLogicalName1 = $CrmRecord1.logicalname
        $Id1 = $CrmRecord1.($EntityLogicalName1 + "id")
    }

    if($CrmRecord2 -ne $null)
    {
        $EntityLogicalName2 = $CrmRecord2.logicalname
        $Id2 = $CrmRecord2.($EntityLogicalName2 + "id")
    }

    try
    {
        $result = $conn.CreateEntityAssociation($EntityLogicalName1, $Id1, $EntityLogicalName2, $Id2, $RelationshipName, [Guid]::Empty)
        if(!$result)
        {
            return $conn.LastCrmException
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return $conn.LastCrmException
    }
}

#CreateMultiEntityAssociation
function Add-CrmMultiRecordAssociation{

<#
 .SYNOPSIS
 Associates multiple records to single record for N:N relationship.

 .DESCRIPTION
 The Add-CrmMultiRecordAssociation cmdlet lets you associate multiple records to single record for N:N relationship by specifying relatioship logical name. 
 Use @('<object>','<object>') syntax to specify multiple ids or records.
 if the relationship is self-referencing, specify $True for -IsReflexiveRelationship Parameter.

 There are two ways to specify records.
 
 1. Pass EntityLogicalName and record's Id for both records.
 2. Get record object(s) by using Get-CrmRecord/Get-CrmRecords cmdlets, and pass them.

 You can specify relationship logical name for the association.

 .PARAMETER conn
 A connection to your CRM organizatoin. Use $conn = Get-CrmConnection <Parameters> to generate it.

 .PARAMETER CrmRecord1
 A first record object which is obtained via Get-CrmRecord/Get-CrmRecords. When you pass CrmRecord, then you don't use EntityLogicalName/Id.

 .PARAMETER CrmRecord2s
 An array of records object which are obtained via Get-CrmRecord/Get-CrmRecords. When you pass CrmRecord, then you don't use EntityLogicalName/Id.

 .PARAMETER EntityLogicalName1
 A logicalname for first Entity. i.e.)accout, contact, lead, etc..

 .PARAMETER Id1
 An Id (guid) of first record

 .PARAMETER EntityLogicalName2
 A logicalname for second Entity. i.e.)accout, contact, lead, etc..

 .PARAMETER Id2s
 An array of Ids (guid) of second records. Specify by using @('66005a70-6317-e511-80da-c4346bc43d94','62005a70-6317-e511-80da-c4346bc43d94') synctax.

 .PARAMETER RelationshipName
 A N:N relationship logical name.

 .PARAMETER IsReflexiveRelationship
 Specify $True if the N:N relationship is self-referencing.

 .EXAMPLE
 Add-CrmMultiRecordAssociation -conn $conn -EntityLogicalName1 account -Id1 00005a70-6317-e511-80da-c4346bc43d94 -EntityLogicalName2 contact -Id2s @('66005a70-6317-e511-80da-c4346bc43d94','62005a70-6317-e511-80da-c4346bc43d94') -RelationshipName new_accounts_contacts
 This example associates an account and two contact records through new_accounts_contacts custom N:N relationship.

 .EXAMPLE
 Add-CrmMultiRecordAssociation account 00005a70-6317-e511-80da-c4346bc43d94 contact @('66005a70-6317-e511-80da-c4346bc43d94','62005a70-6317-e511-80da-c4346bc43d94') new_accounts_contacts
 
 This example associates an account and two contact records through new_accounts_contacts custom N:N relationship by ommiting parameters names.
 When ommiting parameter names, you do not provide $conn, cmdlets automatically finds it.

 .EXAMPLE
 PS C:\>$account = Get-CrmRecord account 00005a70-6317-e511-80da-c4346bc43d94 name

 PS C:\>$fetch = @"
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false" no-lock="true">
  <entity name="contact">
    <attribute name="fullname" />
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="lastname" operator="like" value="%sample%" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
"@

 PS C:\>$contacts = Get-CrmRecordsByFetch $fetch

 PS C:\>Add-CrmMultiRecordAssociation $account $contacts.CrmRecords new_accounts_contacts

 This example retrieves contacts by using FetchXML and stores to a variable, then retrieves and store an account record to another variable.
 Then passes those variables Add-CrmMultiRecordAssociation.
#>

    [CmdletBinding()]
    PARAM(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient]$conn,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1, ParameterSetName="CrmRecord")]
        [PSObject]$CrmRecord1,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2, ParameterSetName="CrmRecord")]
        [PSObject[]]$CrmRecord2s,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1, ParameterSetName="NameWithId")]
        [string]$EntityLogicalName1,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2, ParameterSetName="NameWithId")]
        [guid]$Id1,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=3, ParameterSetName="NameWithId")]
        [string]$EntityLogicalName2,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=4, ParameterSetName="NameWithId")]
        [guid[]]$Id2s,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=5)]
        [string]$RelationshipName,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=6)]
        [bool]$IsReflexiveRelationship
    )

    $conn = VerifyCrmConnectionParam $conn;   

    if($CrmRecord1 -ne $null)
    {
        $EntityLogicalName1 = $CrmRecord1.logicalname
        $Id1 = $CrmRecord1.($EntityLogicalName1 + "id")
    }

    if($CrmRecord2s -ne $null)
    {
        if($CrmRecord2s.Count -ne 0)
        {
            $EntityLogicalName2 = $CrmRecord2s[0].logicalname
            $Ids = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Guid]'
            foreach($CrmRecord2 in $CrmRecord2s)
            {
                $Ids.Add($CrmRecord2.($EntityLogicalName2 + "id"))
            }
            $Id2s = $Ids.ToArray()
        }
         else
        {
            Write-Warning 'CrmRecords2 does not include any records.'
            break;
        }
    }   

    try
    {
        $result = $conn.CreateMultiEntityAssociation($EntityLogicalName1, $Id1, $EntityLogicalName2, $Id2s, $RelationshipName, [Guid]::Empty, $IsReflexiveRelationship)
        if(!$result)
        {
            return $conn.LastCrmException
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return $conn.LastCrmException
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to add the user into a queue.

Pretty sure that section is "Queues I'm a member of", which is the `queuemembership_association` many to many relationship between user and queue.

You will need to issue an [AssociateRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg327615(v%3Dcrm.8)).

Comment: can i do this with powershell ?

Comment: @enzo yes you can. I have extended James answer & given some example below.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to set the default queue field.

[image]

That can only hold one value at a time so I don't think what you are trying to do will work.

If its helpful you could issue the update call twice, this will save both values into CRM, but the last will overwrite the first.

```
[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference] $userent.Attributes["queueid"]=$queue_ref0
Update-Record -OrganizationService $CRMConn -EntityObject $userent –verbose

[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference] $userent.Attributes["queueid"]=$queue_ref1
Update-Record -OrganizationService $CRMConn -EntityObject $userent –verbose
```

Comment: I need to know how i can affect multiple queues to a user and be able to see them in the member's queue field